# Angular listen on subscription start of rxjs observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Is there a way to detect the start of the subcription of a rxjs observable within the pipe?

I want to trigger a loading indicator when a http observable (destroyed when respone has been finalized) get subscribed.

Or do I have to create a wrapper observable for this action?

Comment: read https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what RxJS version you're using. With RxJS < 7.3 you can use `defer()`:

```
defer(() => {
  loadingFlag = true;
  return this.http.doyourrequest().pipe(
    finalize(() => loadingFlag = false),
  );
});
```

Since RxJS >= 7.3 you can use new event handlers for `tap()`:

```
this.http.doyourrequest().pipe(
  tap({
    subscribe: () => loadingFlag = true,
    finalize: () => loadingFlag = false,
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

since every subscription to http observable causes new http call it is safe to set such flag outside of the pipe, at least it is how I do it.

```
getSomeData(){
  loadingFlag=true;
  return this.http.doyourrequest().pipe(finalize(()=>loadingFlag=false));
}
```

if you really want to go trough sub count(which is always down to 0 after every request due to finalizztion of http obs) check the implementation of refCount() and share() operators which internally counts the subscribers

Edit:

You can encapsulate setting of the flag using dummy observable as an entry point eg

```
getSomeData(){
  return of(null).pipe(
      tap(()=>loadingFlag=true),
      switchMapTo(this.http.doyourrequest()),
      finalize(()=>loadingFlag=false)
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. i already have implemented it like you, but im facing the issue that the flag doesnt get set, when i define a variable for it (let obs$ = getSomeData()) due to the reference on the httpobservable.

Comment: you can overcome this using dummy observable as an entry point and switch map to the observable to http - setting the flag in the process. I have added that example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting some indicator as a side effect in your stream, try creating an observable that returns the state of your request.

```
readonly makeRequestSubject = new Subject<RequestParams>();
readonly request$ = makeRequestSubject.pipe(
  switchMap(params => this.doRequest(params).pipe(
    map(result => ({ params, result,  state: 'complete' })),
    catchError(error => ({ error, params, state: 'error' }))
    startWith({ params, state: 'loading' })
  ),
  startWith({ state: 'notstarted' }),
  shareReplay(1)
);
readonly isLoading$ = this.request.pipe(map(x => x === 'loading'), distinctUntilChanged());
readonly results$ = this.request.pipe(map(x => x === 'complete' ? x.results : []));
```

1. You *could* return an observable from a method and use it like an overweight promise, or you could have a single field that contains the stream, and all dependents could just subscribe and unsubscribe to it when they want.  **next()** on **makeRequestSubject** gets called every time you need to make a new request.
2. The outer **startWith** should emit first.  This is optional, but might be useful in some ui scenarios, such as showing a message with instructions if no requests have been made.
3. The request is initiated in a **switchMap** so succcessive calls will interrupt the prior ones if they're not already complete.
4. The inner **startWith** operator will emit first unless the request is instantaneous.
5. **catchError** illustrates another typical use case beyond settings a loading indicator.
6. You could subscribe to **request$** directly, or use **isLoading$** and results$**.  I typically try to avoid creating extra observables, and just make sure the model on my component in a master stream matches up with my ui bindings.
7. Params were just included because they might be useful in the ui.